# How to use 2 directives together - angular-translate & angular-truncate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

1. Using the angular-translate directive:

{{ 'PARAGRAPH' | translate }}

2. Using the angular-truncate directive:

{{ 'PARAGRAPH' | characters:15 }}

How can I use them together?
Can I do the following? Does not seem to work.

{{ 'PARAGRAPH' | translate | characters:15 }}

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

translate & characters are not directives, but filters ...

Also, this is piping, not multi directives.

Read more : [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

ps : sorry I can not yet add comments ...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out {{ 'PARAGRAPH' | translate | characters:15 }} can solve the problem.
Multi directives can work together as long as using the same scope.